# How to restore Virtualbox virtual machine from Snapshot only?

Tags: virtualbox

I lost my Virtualbox image (.vdi) File of my virtual macine, but i got a snapshot file (.vdi), which is huge, so i assume its a complete image of the virtual machine. Virtualbox does not let me attach it nor clone it as it always

Comment: Snapshot files are usually not stand-alone but are some sort of delta regarding a parent image file. If you miss that parent file most likely the snapshot image misses some sectors that are changed in the snapshot which make a recovery very hard.

Answer (score 0):

The first snapshot only contains what changed compared to the base disk,
the second snapshot only contains what changed compared to the first snapshot,
and so on.

The base disk has all of the fundamental filesystem structures.
If you don't have that then there is absolutely no chance of recovery.

Try to find some backup of the base disk, or try to recreate it if it only contains
a standard setup that you can redo.